# sort on non-contiguous fields: POSIX equivalent to 'sort +0 -1 +2'

Tags: shell, unix, sorting

Given file contents:

```
1234  1  15ECS3
1234  2  MS21042
1234  1  16AS338
1235  1  0321042
```

I need to sort by columns 1, then 3, skipping 2, like so:

```
1234  1  15ECS3
1234  1  16AS338
1234  2  MS21042
1235  1  0321042
```

I can get this to work with the following deprecated command:

```
sort +0 -1 +2 file
```

But for the life of me I can't get it to work with the -km.n -km.n equivalent. I've tried:

```
sort -b -k1 -k3 file
```

as my baseline, and about 20 variations on that, throwing all the switches that seem relevant, but that are mostly redundant (a sign of desperation).

What am I missing? What would the posix version of the above working code be?

Thanks in advance.

-Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
sort -k1,1 -k3,3
```

Comment: That did the trick. So does this mean "start sort on field 1 and end on field 1" (-k1,1), "start sort on field 3 and end on field 3" (-k3,3)? Anyway, thank you very much for your help; I couldn't seem to grok the manpage even after googling for copious examples. This helped a ton.